# Mobile Website: hiding 'click confirmation box'

Tags: javascript, mobile

When I click on a button or link in my webbrowser on my Android phone, I see a colored box, confirming I clicked on something.

I am designing a mobile website and I would like to hide this 'click confirmation' - because it is not necessary and ruins the general impression of my site.

Is there a way to make a button or link in JavaScript that doesn't return this colored box when clicked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css on any element you don't want this behaviour (or all elements).

```
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

So to stop all links you could use:

```
a {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```